# Finding the point of concurrence of a family of straight lines

Tags: analytic-geometry

If $6a^2-3b^2-c^2+7ab-ac+4bc=0$, then the family of lines $ax+by+c=0$ is concurrent at

1. $(-2,-3)$
2. $(3,-1)$
3. $(2,3)$
4. $(-3,1)$

Multiple answers are possible.

I am not able to group terms of the expression $6a^2-3b^2-c^2+7ab-ac+4bc=0$ so as to get expression in the form $\lambda_1L_1+\lambda_2L_2=0$, where $L_1$ and $L_2$ denote two lines out of the given family. Please help.

Comment: A first observation is that $6a^2-3b^2-c^2+7ab-ac+4bc=(2a+3 b-c)(3a-b+c)$. This could be helpful.

Comment: @DennisGulko Indeed, your factorization gives immediately the points $(-2,-3)$ and $(3,-1)$ as points on lines $ax+by+c=0.$

Comment: @coffeemath I think 'concurrent' (used by OP) would be the wrong word to use. All we know is that the lines must pass through one of those 2 points. Not all lines need to pass through $(-2,-3)$.

Comment: @Calvin Yes I agree, each line must pass through at least one of the points, not necessarily through either particular point. (+1 on comment)